# add sitemap file to google search console

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sitemap

i have 2 urls https://wixten.com/

https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/

in `https://wixten.com/`  i have hosted my frontend react js

in `https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/` i have hosted my backend express.js

i am trying to connect my sitemap.txt file to googles serch console

even though i  have the sitemap.txt file in the root folder  i am not able to read the file as `https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/sitemap.txt`

[image]

but using get method i was able to get file display it in browser using the below code

```
app.get("/sitemaps2", function (req, res) {
    var fs = require("fs");

    try {
      var data = fs.readFileSync("sitemap.txt", "utf8");
      res.send(data);
      // console.log(data.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error:", e.stack);
    }
  });
```

[image]

i want to add the sitmap.txt to googles search console but with get method its not possible
and also i have google search console domain added is  `https://wixten.com/`  but the `sitemap.txt` file is in  `https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/`
[image]

if the given details are not possible to find the problem i can provide my heroku and firebase credential for anyone who is willing to help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file/response format is not correct you should create in this format.

Doc:https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap

```
http://www.example.com/file1.html http://www.example.com/file2.html
```

Suggest in the google doc.

```
http://www.example.com/file1.html
http://www.example.com/file2.html

const data = fs.readFileSync("sitemap.txt", "utf8");
const urls = data.split(" ");
res.send(urls);
```

**Another Solution: You can create XML format**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/foo.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-06-04</lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

**Best way is**
You could do is serve sitemap as a static file, why you want to read the text file and serve from API.

Comment: i cannot serve sitmap as staic because new url are added daily  to  sitemap.txt when a question is posted

Comment: ur anwer is not helping me neither how to read sitemap.txt in `https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/sitemap.txt `

Comment: nor how to add  `https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/sitemaps2` to search console

Comment: sir do u have any answers pls  help

Comment: ttps://ask-over.herokuapp.com/sitemap.txt   i have fixed reading the file in this url can u tell me how i can add it to serch console